# Unpacking a Rails Bundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

What is the command/procedure to unpack a Rails 3.0.3 bundle if I need to update local gems? I am using the bundle gem versions 1.0.0.rc.6.

I am working for a client that has very restrict internet rules and accesses. As such, they do not want to let an application be able to access the internet RubyGem or Git libraries.

I am planning to use the command "bundle package" and place all the gem files locally on their server.

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bundle package copies the gems used by the app to vendor/cache, when you deploy to their server the gems will get copied as well.

Thereafter, if you need to update the gems, simply run bundle update and it will update the gems in vendor/cache. Then redeploy.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for:

`bundle install --deployment`

it vendorizes the gems locally